# How to continue running scripts when exiting docker containers

Tags: docker

My script is as follows:

```
# start a ubuntu container in the background
docker run -it --name ub -d ubuntu /bin/bash
sleep 1

# run a command in the container
docker exec -it ub bash
echo 234

# exit the container
exit
sleep 1

# do something else
echo 123
```

But the script would just stop right after `exit` and hang there. Does anyone know why is that?

p.s: My Docker version is: 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22

Answer (score 2):

You have given `-it` during the run command. which opens up the `/bin/bash` of your container and waits there. The next command wont get executed until the first command execution is completed.

It's better to create a script file and move it inside the container while making the docker. and run the script on starting the docker. You may specify that using a `CMD` in the docker file.

You won't be needing an additional exec command.

The corresponding Dockerfile would be

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY <path-to-script> <dest> 

CMD [" <path-to-script> "]
```

You have to create the script file along with the Dockerfile. Build the docker using the command

```
docker build -t <image-name> <location of Dockerfile>
```

The execution command would be

```
docker run -d --name <name> -d ubuntu <path-to-script>
```

Comment: the actual image that I wanted to run is mongo (https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/). And it seems that I can't even run the bash scripts even if I want to if I use this as the base image?

Comment: You need to build the  custom Docker image with the corresponding script file in it. You shouldn't run and execute it as a bash script.

Comment: The Dockerfile of mongo is available over here https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/4a81205a13fefc418355248f750551e4f7c62361/3.0/Dockerfile. You can edit it and create a custom docker.

Comment: Agree with above approach and wanted to add one more point. To keep running container there must be a process which running continuously. Add the below line at the end of script.                                                 while true; do
    something_in_the_background
done &

Comment: I see. ok lemme try it this way then.

Comment: I created a Dockerfile based on tutum/mongodb:3.2. With this image you can do `docker run -e MONGODB_PASS="mypass" tutum/mongodb` and pass the parameters when you specify `FROM tutum/mongodb:3.2` in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes you can set the environment variables in Docker file using `ENV`. Please do refer the link below. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement.

Comment: Hope the question is answered!